# Is there a __str__ function that returns the Linked List in order?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, linked-list

This is a program for a class I'm taking. I cannot add any functions. I need to edit only the **str** function. This is the first and most crucial part of the assignment. It seems no matter what I try, when I print b after creating str functions with while loops or if statements, 40 is the only number returned. Also, the code below comes from three different files in the same folder. Every other function works and runs well for me. Thanks for any help!

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo=None, next=None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next  = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)`

from MyNode import Node

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None

    def add_first(self, cargo):
        node = Node(cargo)
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.length += 1    

from MyNode import Node
from MyLinkedList import LinkedList
b = LinkedList()
b.add_first(20)
b.add_first(10)
b.add_first(30)
b.add_first(250)
b.add_first(50)
b.add_first(40)

print(b)
```

Comment: We cannot answer test questions here, it's against community guidelines. If this is not a test, your teacher should be able to help you. But, to give you some guidance, I'm not familiar with python, but it looks like you are only printing the first item in the list, try iterating through it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Right now, `return str(self.cargo)` of course will only print the "cargo" of the first node. What else would you expect? If you want to print the rest of the list, you need to additionally access the `self.next` property and call its string method until it becomes None, which is the recursive base case. For the purposes of this question, there's no point in having 3 files, so you can remove the imports. See also [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and good luck.